# Can one plugin activate another plugin via script?

Tags: plugin-development

Can one plugin activate another plugin via script?

I know its possible to [deactivate known plugins via script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11934/is-it-possible-to-uninstall-one-plugin-from-within-another-plugin), but can't find any examples of how to activate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

```
function activate_plugin( $plugin, $redirect = '', $network_wide = false, $silent = false );
```

in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php

Comment: Thanks Bainternet! I don't think I'll need this now after all, since I found the solution (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/calling-clean-term-cache-fails-when-called-in-the-same-plugin-that-creates-term) to the problem that I was going to use this as a workaround for, but it will definitely come in handy in the future.